# Django multipleselect selected data

Tags: django, forms

I've been trying to crack this nut for a while but I cannot seem to be able to set selected values for multipleselect. What I have is:

```
class GroupUsersForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupUsersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('initial'):
            self.selected = kwargs['initial']['users']
            self.choices = kwargs['initial']['all']
        self.fields[self.get_field_name()] = self.get_users_field()

    def get_users_field(self):
        field_class = forms.MultipleChoiceField
        field = field_class(
            label=_(u"users"),
            choices = self.get_field_choices(),
            widget = FilteredSelectMultiple(_(u"users"), is_stacked= False),
            #initial = self.get_field_initial(),
            required= False
        )
        return field

    def get_field_name(self):
        return 'users'

    def get_field_choices(self):
        choices = [(p.id, p.username) for p in self.choices]       
        return choices

    def get_field_initial(self):
        selected = [(p.id, p.username) for p in self.selected]
        return selected
```

and i initiate it like that:

```
uform = GroupUsersForm(initial = {'all': users, 'users':u, 'group':g,})
```

both users and u are querysets (

```
users = get_users_with_perms(a).order_by('username', 'last_name', 'first_name')

u = User.objects.filter(Q(groups = g)).order_by('username', 'last_name', 'first_name'))
```

which in one test case were even the same. 
No selected options showed up.

I tried setting the initial values myself manually to list based of object ids, passing single id, passing (id, username) tuple and so on... tried using different widget, but all widgets display all the options but none of them are selected.

what am i doing wrong?

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the choices property of the users field. The value of 'users' in the initial dict should be a list of whatever the keys are for the user choices. For example, if

```
self.fields['users'].choices = (
                               ('username1','Firstname Lastname'),
                               ('username2','Firstname Lastname'),
                               ('username3','Firstname Lastname'),
                               )
```

Initial should be `['username1', 'username3']`

Then change your form instantiation and `__init__` to the following:

```
uform = GroupUsersForm(users, initial = {'users':u,})

def __init__(self, user_choices, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GroupUsersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['users'].choices = user_choices
```

Comment: allright. Basically, as i figured it out, the thing that i was doing wrong was that i did not specify initial data in correct format. I was thinking that you needed to pass same type of info as initial data as the choices.